# Best place to ask about unsolicited email issues

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm having an issue with a major California-based company not honouring Unsubscribe requests and I keep receiving emails from them.

I'd like to know who I can contact to lodge an official complaint. Where's the best place to ask?

(That is essentially the question)

Comment: I'm relatively certain that there's also a national registry for spam emailers; in addition, if you use Gmail (and possibly Yahoo Mail or others, but I'm not sure) you can set up filters looking for emails they use, keywords that appear in their messages, etc. to flag them as spam before you ever see them.

Comment: Ask on SuperUser how to configure your email client to block them as spam.

Comment: Chances are I can configure the email account to block them, but it's more of an ethical thing for me at this point. They're not honouring the unsubscribe requests, which means it's possibly not just me who's getting this issue, so I feel that informing whoever the Californian equivalent of the ICO is is probably the best course of action.

Comment: @KazikM please don't make such minor edits on posts this ancient. That only bumps these questions for which no-one has a current interest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest [Law.SE](http://law.stackexchange.com) for this, but make sure you read the help there to check if it's on-topic first.

The reason I suggest Law is because they *could* be breaking laws by not honouring unsubscribe requests - although I'm not sure of the laws that apply in your jurisdiction.

**Edit:** looks like [these laws](http://www.spamlaws.com/state/ca.shtml) might apply, so it's probably at least on topic at Law

Comment: That was my first thought as well, but I wasn't entirely sure. The issue is I'm UK based, they're California based so I'm unsure about who to contact

Comment: @DarkHippo Just edited above with a link to CA spam laws. You're essentially asking if you can do anything from another jurisdiction. Here in Australia, the spam laws prevent AU companies from sending spam overseas (including not honouring unsubscribe requests). So yeah, I'd definitely ask this on Law if you haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for including that link :)